# rewritecond to check if its a script or a client

Tags: mod-rewrite, client

My site works by including pages from the 'pages' directory (PHP), and I would like to forbid access to the files in that directory. However, when I put a .htaccess file in there saying: `deny from all`, it forbid access to the files for everything, not just a request to incude a file or use a stylesheet.

I also tried bringing the user to another page when they try to look at those files like so:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\ /?].*HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?path=1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.css[\ /?].*HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?path=1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.js[\ /?].*HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?path=1 [QSA]
```

And that works, it just doesn't let the stylesheets/js be loaded. It does let the PHP files be included but not viewed, which is nice, so I'm fine with keeping the third of those three. But my css files contain information about my file structure that I'd rather not divulge to a hacker. So, I don't want those to be publicly available.

Anyway...My question is:
**Is there a** `RewriteCond` **that I could put in front if the last two to make them only apply if the request is coming from a client?**
i.e.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} IS_COMING_FROM_A_CLIENT_OR_BROWSER
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.css[\ /?].*HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?path=1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} IS_COMING_FROM_A_CLIENT_OR_BROWSER
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.js[\ /?].*HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?path=1 [QSA]
```

P.S. I would prefer not to do it through `deny from all` and that sort of thing if possible as I am on shared hosting and they might not like that.

Comment: How do you know when is coming from a client?

Comment: The site is still in development. I know because I type it into my address bar.

Comment: Well, I guess you know but my question is trying to determine the difference between a client's request and any other. There has to be something to identify the incoming URLs, otherwise it is impossible to filter them with a `RewriteCond` and the answer to your question would be NO.

Answer (score 0):

Would checking that HTTP_REFERER is something other than the .php page work for the .js and .css file inclusions?